# Call application API inside an Android application

Tags: android

I have downloaded a file manager application called "AndExplorer" inside my Android emulator.
My goal is to call this application inside my current custom application. Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: You'll have to look at the documentation for that particular application

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends, you could use Intents if AndExplorer allows, something like this:

```
public Button.OnClickListener mExplore = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.path.to.ANDEXPLORER");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int possibleCode, int possibleOption, Intent intent) {
    //Process the data
    }
}
```

Edit: A quick Google, http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andexplorer/#faq

Comment: By the way, do you know if there is any default Files Manager API for Android? I am trying to implement a browse button where user can choose a file and the full filepath will be returned to my app. It is quite stupid if I need to fully depend on AndExplorer app if I want to implement this functionality.